# Fog error: nodename nor servname provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fog

I have the following set up for FOG basically [right out of the FOG website](http://fog.io/1.7.0/storage/):

```
  def fog_save_file_for(filename, file) 
# create a connection
connection = Fog::Storage.new({
  :provider                 => 'AWS',
  :aws_access_key_id        => '##',
  :aws_secret_access_key    => '##'
})

directory = connection.directories.get('upload_dir')

# list directories
#p connection.directories

# upload that resume
file = directory.files.create(
  :key    => filename,
  :body   => File.open("cv_uploads/provider_cvs/"+filename),
  :public => true
)
end
```

at run time I get the following error:

```
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
```

Comment: Same here, ever got this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is probably caused by using an incorrect region. Carrierwave/Fog defaults to "us-east-1" which is not necessarily your correct region. To fix this, go lookup your region on AWS (this will not be a country name like "Ireland" but a region like "eu-west-1), then modify your config file to include the following:

```
 :region => 'eu-west-1', #or whatever your region is
```